# Python dtypes doesnt return all int and float

Tags: python

```
a = [i for i in b.columns if b[i].dtypes in ["int", "float"]]
```

When i type the code, dtype doesn't return int64 and float64. It takes only int32 and float32.

I don't want to type like this:

```
a = [i for i in b.columns if b[i].dtypes in ["int32", "int64", "float32", "float64"]]
```

When i type just the first code it should return all int and float types. I am not sure where is the mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Hello can you share your input data sample.

Comment: `[i for i in b.columns if np.issubdtype(dtype := b[i].dtypes, np.integer) or np.issubdtype(dtype, np.floating)]`